# (Scrapy) Unable to extract HREF from html

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

```
next_page = response.css('body > div.bg-theme-b.page-results.page-listing-results.page-results-responsive.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-active > div.ui-panel-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(10) > div > ul > li.ui-block-b > a').extract_first()

    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I am trying to scrape house price data from m.zoopla.co.uk (mobile because it seems to be nicer to scrape data from...). I cannot get scrapy to pick up the href attribute on the link for the next page. The data is scraped from the first page fine - no problems there.

I've used the longest, most direct CSS selector as shown here - it doesnt work. I've tried with a shorter selector: `response.css('li.ui-block-b > a::attr(href)').extract_first()` and it still returns as None.

I have also tried using the XPath. No cigar there either. Please help. Someone. Anyone..

PS. Only included the code for the next page as there are no errors and the actual data scraping works fine.

Comment: Please provide the exact `url` you are scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply select the `<a>` element which have attribute `data-icon="carat-r"` and then get `href`, as only next page link has the attribute `data-icon="carat-r"`.

```
next_page = response.css('a[data-icon*=carat-r]::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

**Output:**

```
2017-05-03 13:27:53 [quotes] DEBUG: next_page is /house-prices/browse/coalville/?pn=2
```